# Terraform aws iot sitewise resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am trying to create an IoT Sitewise asset in aws using terraform however it is not listed in documentation. Is there a way for me to create this or is it not supported by the provider yet? By the way I am very new to these concepts so please do not mind me if I am asking something obvious.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that as of right now, IoT Sitewise is not supported by Terraform. IoT Sitewise was just launched last month. Terraform is updated regularly with new AWS services, so the best way to find out when it becomes supported is to keep an eye on the [AWS Provider Documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs) in Terraform's documentation. Search for "IoT" in the navigation pane and it will populate in the search results when they have added support.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `awscc` (AWS Cloud Control) provider: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/awscc/latest/docs/resources/iotsitewise_asset. Later on, when it makes it to the official `aws` provider, you can switch to it.